# Finding compatible thinner street tires for Giant ATX

Tags: mountain-bike, road-bike, giant

I am trying to get a pair of thinner road tires for my Giant ATX (Disc). I have tried to look up resources to see what tires would be compatible with the bike but could not find anything.

Can someone suggest what road tires would be compatible. I have a 26 inch model. I am new to biking so have very little idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which year is your bike, (if you have no exact date, at least approximate, when did you buy it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any 26" tyre will be fine, as long as it

1. Fits between your chainstays/seatstays/brakes/fork when mounted without rubbing
2. isn't too small (or big) for your rim's internal width
3. **has exactly the same ETRTO diameter**

Most of the versions of that bike seem to have a 2.1" width tyre, so its likely you'll be able to fit a 1.5" to 2.1" wide 26 inch tyre without issue.   26 inch is also known by the ETRTO size 559 or 559-widthinmm so yours probably have 559-53 or 53-559 on the sidewall.

> Just to confuse things, there are <26"> tyres that have a different ETRTO code, or may be so old that they don't have such a code.  You're not likely to find these on your bike, but you might find them for sale.  The ETRTO codes could be "26 inch" are 559mm, 571mm, 584mm, 590mm or 597mm.   You need to match whats on your existing tyres.

If you want thinner than 1.5" (or ~38mm) then you'll want to measure the inner valley width of the rim and compare it to the chart at [What is the maximum or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle)?

Remember to buy 3 new tubes as well, two for the bike and one in your bag as the spare.

---

My commuter bike is 26" wheel as well, and finding fast road-oriented tyres is challenging - the range is very small for sporty offerings, so you will probably be looking at commuter-tyres which tend to be more puncture resistant.  Still much faster than using knobbly tyres on the road.

Comment: A 26 x 1-1/4 won't fit.  A 26 x 1-3/4 won't fit.  Only 26" tires with decimal widths will fit.

Comment: @srt2018 For an inspiration on the possible tyres/models, have a look at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/skinny-26-tires-giveing-a-small-fixie-a-faster-look/2117#2117 very old answers, but you can have an inspiration about some tyre manufacturers and their products

Comment: @EarlGrey that question is quite old, and we've moved away from making product recommendations because they go stale fairly quickly.  The answer above tries to be helpful without saying "get a X tyre" because when that is no longer available, the whole answer becomes unhelpful.  What's above should assist OP in finding a good sized tyre for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @Criggie ok, got it, I commented here exactly because you gave already a good general description how to find the wheel, but a complete beginner may not know the brand of tyres and unfortunately the famous search enginge g****e now is full of crap and it is quite hard to find information about products without ending up on a page trying to sell you some crap similar to what you are trying to investigate.